# Load multi CSV files from local disc to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql, java, csv

I want to load a lot of CSV files from a local disc in an already created postgres database. Which is the easiest way to do that? By using SQL or Java? I suppose that I need a loop for doing that, but how to implement loop in SQL?

Comment: I posted a possible solution. I am not sure what OS you are using, but you should be able to use it on any, but might need some work to adapt to Windows.

Comment: There does not seem to be a GIS component to this question which I think would be better researched/asked at [dba.se] or [so].

Comment: Actually, those CSV files contain GPS points and have to be imported in postgres for further GIS analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux/Mac or on Windows using cygwin you can simply call the `psql` command in a loop, using Postgres's built in [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) command. You use the `-c` switch to psql to indicate that you are running the command inside the quotes. This works well because you can use the operating system to get the list of files very easily. For example,

```
for x in $(ls file_name*.csv); 
do psql -c "copy table_name from '/path/todir/$x' csv" db_name; done
```

where you need to replace file_name, table_name and db_name and the path with something appropriate to your system. file_name*.csv can be any regular expression that matches your file names, for example, the above would match file_name1.csv, file_name2.csv, etc.

If you want to do this within Postgres itself, you will need to use dynamic SQL inside a plpgsql function and loop through calling COPY multiple times with a file list that you will have to send to the function. This is considerably more painful, as you not only have to pass and parse the list within the function, but you also lose the ability to do expression searches on the filesystem as with the `ls file_name*.csv` example above.

If you are on Windows and don't have cygwin, I am sure there is any easy way using Power Shell or similar -- just don't ask me how :D. Java I would regard as overkill for this, though obviously you could do it.

Comment: Just in case anyone else has trouble with the above script, I had to tweak it and this is what worked for me in the end:   for x in $(ls /path/to/files/file_name*.csv); 
do psql -c "COPY table_name FROM '$x' CSV HEADER" db_name; done

Comment: @Matt, ok, well, CSV HEADER addresses a different issue, but, yes, good point.

Comment: @John think it was swapping the path from 'do' to 'for' that fixed it for me. Not an expert in shell scripting so not too sure why!

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but the `\copy` command is not recognizing `'$x'` - `‘$x’: No such file or directory`. When I do something simple like `for x in $(ls *.csv); do echo "hello $x"; done;` it prints out the filenames of $x just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use [GDAL ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) utility.  If all your csv are in one directory this terminal statement (using OSGeo4W Shell) should work:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=myserver.abc.com port=54321 user=postgres dbname=mydbname password=mypassword" C://Temp
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create one install.sql file that has all the csv file name like below.
Install.sql file contains below entries

```
    \ir demodile.csv
    \ir demofile1.csv
```

Execute the below

```
    psql -h <<hostnam>> -U <<username>> -d <<database>> -f Install.sql
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer? Judging from the question, he was trying to avoid manually specifying each file name.

Comment: You maintain one install.sql file and update that file with all the csv file names.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your answer to revise it with any requested clarifications.